# How to Disable resize window on mouse over edge

Tags: mac, windows, mouse, window-manager, macos

I have my window in full screen and I want to scroll. In Windows, I would just move the mouse all the way to the right side of the screen where the scroll bar is. Then I would click down and scroll. But for Mac, instead of being able to scroll, it shows the drag/resize window cursor and if I press down and move it, it resizes the window.

Is there any way to make it so that I can just scroll the window instead of resizing it?

I'm using BetterTouchTool if there is no built in function and it would help with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Don't click, just scroll.

Mac will scroll any window the cursor is over, whether it's foregrounded or not. You don't even need the cursor to be over the scroll-bar, just anywhere in that window.

The only exception to this is if your cursor is inside any specifically scrollable area within the window, such as the following example - this will override the main window scroll & scroll that specific area instead.

<sup>random kernel panic data copied from another Ask Different question</sup>

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff802cf70d0d): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.128: expected 0xffffff8069109580 but found 0xffffff8069119580, bits changed 0x10000, at offset 0 of 128 in element 0xffffff80620cff80, cookies 0x3f00118b7d7cb634 0x5352144d41da7e3"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.10.72/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:496
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8215e2b0c0 : 0xffffff802cf2fe41 
0xffffff8215e2b140 : 0xffffff802cf70d0d 
0xffffff8215e2b1b0 : 0xffffff802cf70811 
0xffffff8215e2b1f0 : 0xffffff802cf6f657 
0xffffff8215e2b320 : 0xffffff802d36a00b 
0xffffff8215e2b3f0 : 0xffffff802d3699d5 
0xffffff8215e2b4e0 : 0xffffff802d166802 
0xffffff8215e2b650 : 0xffffff802d1741e4 
0xffffff8215e2b6b0 : 0xffffff802d16f0b4 
0xffffff8215e2b730 : 0xffffff802d149f64 
0xffffff8215e2bb50 : 0xffffff802d39fc12 
0xffffff8215e2bbb0 : 0xffffff802d164f17 
0xffffff8215e2bc00 : 0xffffff802d15d143 
0xffffff8215e2bf20 : 0xffffff802d1523fa 
0xffffff8215e2bf50 : 0xffffff802d44b386 
0xffffff8215e2bfb0 : 0xffffff802d036e86 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: icbaccountsd

Mac OS version:
14C109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x000000002cc00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802ce00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802cd00000
System model name: iMac12,1 (Mac-942B5BF58194151B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 13465628889363
last loaded kext at 2954176650039: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs    1.10 (addr 0xffffff7fafcb2000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 3097413036585: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7fafcb2000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.symantec.kext.SymAPComm 12.7.1f4
com.symantec.kext.fw    5.3.1f4
com.symantec.kext.filesecurity  12.7f4
com.symantec.kext.ips   3.9.2f1
com.symantec.kext.pf    5.7.1f4
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity  5.4f4
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.3.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.3.0
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.3.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  700.74.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  262.33.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.3.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

System Profile:
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros 9380: 4.0.74.0-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 22.1
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3035312E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3035312E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3035312E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3037332E4130304C4620
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD1001FALS-403AA0, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
Model: iMac12,1, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.71f22
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 512 MB
```

Comment: Yes I know that, it’s a good feature Mac has. But I’m used to loving my mouse all the way to the right of the screen/window where the scroll bar is, clicking it, and then moving it down or up to scroll up or down but only realizing that I’m resizing the window. It gets pretty annoying

Comment: ...then learn not to:) Windows has the most irritating scroll behaviour ever. Once you get used to this way, you'll wonder how you ever managed before. If you **do** want to click in the scroll-bar, that's possible too, just don't go for the very edge of the window, keep in the scroll area itself... & don't use the scroll; the thumb will move to where you click [or down one page, depending on your prefs setup.]

Comment: BTW, I can't repro your issue in fullscreen. I can if the window is maximised, as that is still 'windowed' but in 'real fullscreen' it doesn't happen. Another way to scroll by one page [in things like web browsers, not in anything with an active text area] is to tap the Spacebar.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, not real full screen. I was talking about just the whole window spanning across the screen left to right

Comment: "Don't click, just scroll" is NOT a solution, but "use it as Apple designed it for you". If I want to drag the scroll bar to drag it faster down, even faster than how the pad does, that resize feature doesn't let me do it.

Comment: @user2342558 No-one else seems to have repro'd that bug/feature. That's not how it normally works - apart from anything else, you *can't* resize a fullscreen window.